# Proof $\operatorname{Sin}(x)$ is continuous using addition formula

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

> **Show that the sine function $\operatorname{Sin}: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\to\sin(x)$ is continuous.**

I know how to do other proofs but the hint given is: *Write $\sin(x)$ as $\sin(a+(x-a))$*.

I know that this then is equal to $\sin(a)\cos(x-a)+\sin(x-a)\cos(a)$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Or use $\sin x-\sin a = 2\sin\frac{x-a}2\cos\frac{x+a}2$ for easier bounds on the function value difference. -- How did you define the sine and cosine? How is the inequality $\sin|x|<|x|$ motivated or derived in your course?

Answer (score 1):

If one knows that, as $h \to 0$,
$$
\sin h \to 0, \qquad \cos h\to1,
$$ then using what you have found
$$
\sin x=\sin(a)\cos(x-a)+\sin(x-a)\cos(a)
$$ gives, as $x \to a$,
$$
\sin x \to \sin a,
$$ since both functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ are bounded by $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm  confused to how you went from sin(a)cos(x-a) + sin(x-a)cos(a) to sinx→sina

Comment: @Tommy By using theorems concerning sum and product of limits, one has $\lim_{x \to a} (\sin(a)\cos(x-a)+\sin(x-a)\cos(a))$ $=\sin(a)\lim_{x \to a} (\cos(x-a))+\cos(a)\lim_{x \to a} (\sin(x-a))$ $=\sin (a)\times 1+\cos (a) \times 0=\sin(a).$

Answer (score 0):

Aside from addition formulas, we will assume following facts of sine and cosine:

- $\sin\theta$ is monotonic increasing from $0$ to $1$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.
- $\cos\theta$ is monotonic decreasing from $1$ to $0$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

For any $\theta \in (0,\frac12)$, take an integer $N \ge 2$ such that $N\theta \le 1 < (N+1)\theta$. We have

$$\sin(N\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^N(\sin(k\theta) - \sin((k-1)\theta)
= \sum_{k=1}^N 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\left(\left(k-\frac12\right)\theta\right)$$
On the LHS, $N\theta \in (0,1]$ and $\sin\theta$ increasing there implies $\sin(N\theta) \le \sin(1)$.

On the RHS, all $\left(k - \frac12\right)\theta \in (0,1]$ and $\cos\theta$ decreasing there implies $\cos\left(\left(k - \frac12\right)\theta\right) \ge \cos(1)$.

Combine these, we find

$$ 
\sin(1) \ge 2N\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos(1)
\quad\implies\quad
2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \le \frac{\tan(1)}{N} = \theta\frac{\tan(1)}{N\theta}
\le \theta\frac{\tan(1)}{1 - \theta} \le (2\tan(1))\theta
$$
The last two inequalities are true because $N\theta \le 1 < (N+1)\theta$ and $\theta < \frac12$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2\tan(1)}, \frac12\right)$.

For any $x < y$ with $|x - y| < \delta$, above result implies

$$|\sin x - \sin y| = 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\left|\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right|
\le 2 \left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right| \le 2\tan(1)|x-y| \le \epsilon$$

So $\sin x$ is not only continuous, it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Prove f(x)=sin(x) is continuous at every point x=c.
Use theorem 1: Function f is continuous at c if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0}f(c+h) = f(c)$
Use theorem 2: $\lim_{x \to 0}sin(x) = 0$
Use theorem 3: $\lim_{x \to 0}cos(x) = 1$
Use Trig identity: $\sin (h+c) = sin(h)cos(c) + cos(h)sin(c)$

Proof:
$\lim_{h \to 0}\sin (h+c) = \lim_{h \to 0}\left [sin(h)cos(c) + cos(h)sin(c)  \right ]$ by Trig identity.
Sum and product limit laws allow us to simplify to
$\lim_{h \to 0}\sin (h+c) = (\lim_{h \to 0}sin(h))(\lim_{h \to 0}cos(c)) + (\lim_{h \to 0}cos(h))(\lim_{h \to 0}sin(c))$
Theorems 2 and 3 allow us to simplify to
$\lim_{h \to 0}\sin (h+c) = (0)(\lim_{h \to 0}cos(c)) + (1)(\lim_{h \to 0}sin(c))$
$\lim_{h \to 0}\sin (h+c) = (\lim_{h \to 0}sin(c))$
$\lim_{h \to 0}\sin (h+c) = sin(c)$

Note that the previous equation is true for any value of c.
Therefore, by theorem 1 above, f(x)=sin(x) is continuous at every point x=c.